# How to understand this simplification?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, factorial

I have a problem exercize in which the context isn't relevant to my confusion.What I want is to understand how the factorials in the solution are manipulated in order to simplify the equation.

$$ 1(1!) + 2(2!) + ... + n(n!) + (n+1)[(n+1)!] = (n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)[(n+1)!]$$

Then they simplify it the right side:

$$(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)[(n+1)!]$$
They re-orgarnize the terms so nothing confusing here:

$$(n+1)! + (n+1)[(n+1)!] - 1$$

However this is confusing:
$$(n+1)! + [1 + ( n + 1)] - 1$$
**Now how did they go from $(n+1)[(n+1)!] -1 $ to $[1 + ( n + 1)] - 1$ ?**

They then proceed:
$$(n+1)![n+2] - 1$$
$$(n+2)[(n+1)!] - 1$$
$$(n+2) - 1$$
**Now how did they go from $(n+2)[(n+1)!] - 1$ to $(n+2) - 1$ ?**

Comment: $(n+1)!+(n+1)*(n+1)!=(n+1)!*(1+n+1)=(n+1)!*(n+2)=(n+2)!$ this is just $ab+ac=a(b+c)$ distributivity.

Comment: I think you have a typo.  Obviously $(n+1)[(n+1)!]-1 \ne  [1+(n+1)]-1= n+1$.  I think they meant $(n+1)! + (n+1)[(n+1)!] - 1 = (n+1)![ 1+(n+1)] - 1$. (multiply; not add)

Comment: And obviously $(n+2)[(n+1)!] - 1 \ne (n+2) -1$.  But i think they meant $(n+2)[(n+1)!] - 1 = (n+2)! -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you or the book are making *lots* of typos:

$1(1!) + 2(2!) + ... + n(n!) + (n+1)[(n+1)!] = (n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)[(n+1)!]$

$= (n+1)! + (n+1)[(n+1)!] - 1$.  Now factor out the common term $(n+1)!$ to get:

$= (n+1)! [ 1 + (n+1)] - 1$. This is $(n+1)!$ **TIMES** $[ 1 + (n+1)]$ then $-1$; not $(n+1)!$ **PLUS** $[ 1 + (n+1)]$ then $-1$.

We then continue:

$= (n+1)! [n + 2] - 1$.  And obviously $(n+1)!(n+2) = [1*2*3*...*(n+1)](n+2) = (n+2)!$ so we get:

$= (n+2)! - 1$.  That is $(n+2)$**FACTORIAL**$ -1$ and not $(n+2)$**DON'T DO NOTHIN'**$ -1$.

And the final result is $=(n+2)! -1$.

......

IMO the hardest part to get is

$1*1! + 2*2! + ... +n*n! = (n+1)! -1$.

Is this the inductive step of a proof by induction?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we're proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n kk! = (n+1)! - 1$ by induction.

But there are some typographical errors. The algebra should go:
$$
(n+1)!-1+(n+1)[(n+1)!]=(n+1)![1+(n+1)] - 1 = (n+1)!(n+2) - 1 = (n+2)!-1
$$